# Simple Kendo UI remote DataSource returns empty

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

Here is a simple example I'm trying to build as an exercise and my DataSource object returns with no data.

```
var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "data.json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });

        console.dir( data );
```

data.json

```
[
    {
        "text": "Brand One"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Two"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Three"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Four"
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your code

1. First you need to call **data.read()** - so the request is performed
2. Since the operation above is an async one, invoking **data.data()** wont return anything if you call this immediately after using the **data.read()**. To wait until the data is retrieved you will need to use the [requestEnd](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#requestend) event.

Answer (score -1):

I can load load array to datasource and returns object, see

```
var data_input= [
    {
        "text": "Brand One"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Two"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Three"
    },
    {
        "text": "Brand Four"
    }
];

var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    data: data_input,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });

console.log(data)
```

Comment: transport.read.data is used to send additional parameters to the remote service. You can just assign data to transport.read.data

If this helps: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data